# accessing kinect data

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey,
I am trying to track human motions using openni_kinect and ros. After the user is identified, kinect sends out messages to my terminal with coordinates of various points like knees,foot,etc. How do I record these data? I also wanted to know how to narrow down the data so that I can subscribe to the data of only one reference point, say the right knee.
Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12604/accessing-kinect-data/) by [rockz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1632/rockz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-01-11**:
I don't use human tracking, but I suppose you can find out a lot about the offered information by using the commands "rosnode list", "rosnode info ", "rostopic list", "rostopic info " and "rostopic echo "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try looking at the following [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php#ground-based-rgbd-people-detection) from PCL. If that doesn't help but you are all ready printing this information out to the terminal you could simply create an intermediary node that would take in all of the information and have it publish a series of messages that would contain the information for the coordinates that you are looking for. Once you have the node to do this you can "record" the information by either writing it to the ROS Log file or you can write it to your own log file if you want to.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) with karma: 91 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0